# Unit testing for ServiceBusReceivedMessage

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

My project is in java, I am moving from "com.microsoft.azure:azure-servicebus" to "com.azure:azure-messaging-servicebus".
The migration was successful, but I am facing issues in writing unit tests.
I wanted to create a object of ServiceBusReceivedMessage but not able to do so.

1. Constructor of this is private.
2. Some site suggest to use - ServiceBusModelFactory to create object of ServiceBusReceivedMessage but I could not find that in java SDK.
3. Could not mock it with easy mock as the class is final.

Any idea's on how to write unit test of this.

Comment: Does this [wiki page about mocking final classes](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/wiki/Unit-Testing#mocking-final-classes) help?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [Xie Yijun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12861331/xie-yijun). Posting your suggestions as answer to help other community members.

Customers using the Azure SDK client libraries can mock service clients using [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org/) with `org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker`. More information can be found at [Mock the unmockable: opt-in mocking of final classes/methods](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/What%27s-new-in-Mockito-2#unmockable).

Example code

```
public class TelemetryEvents {
    private final EventHubConsumerAsyncClient consumerClient;
    public TelemetryEvents (EventHubConsumerAsyncClient consumerClient) {
        this.consumerClient = consumerClient;
    }
    
    public Flux<TelemetryEvent> getEvents() {
        return consumerClient.receiveFromPartition("1", EventPosition.latest())
                .map(event -> new TelemtetryEvent(event));
    }
}
```

Test Code

```
import reactor.test.publisher.TestPublisher;
import reactor.test.StepVerifier;

import static com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

public class TelemetryEventsTest {
    @Test
    public void canGetEvents() {
        // Arrange

        // After following the instructions in "Steps" section
        EventHubConsumerAsyncClient consumerClient = mock(EventHubConsumerAsyncClient.class);

        TestPublisher<EventData> eventsPublisher = TestPublisher.createCold();
        eventsPublisher.emit(new EventData("Foo"), new EventData("Bar"));
        when(consumerClient.receiveFromPartition(eq("1"), eq(EventPosition.latest())).thenReturn(eventsPublisher.flux());

        TelemetryEvents telemetryEvents = new TelemetryEvents(consumerClient);

        // Act
        StepVerifier.create(telemetryEvents.getEvents())
            .assertNext(event -> isMatchingTelemetry(event))
            .assertNext(event -> isMatchingTelemetry(event))
            .verifyComplete();        
    }
}
```

For further information Check [Mocking Final Classes](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/wiki/Unit-Testing#mocking-final-classes)